# With Ionic 3 How to make the slides start at the end?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

If I have 3 slides, when the view loads, I would like to see the slide number 3 first. Start by the end, not by the slide 1.

I tried:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.slides.slideTo(3)
}
```

but it throws an error:
    Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an `initialSlide` input property [REF]https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/#Input Properties

in the view you can just add

```
<ion-slides initialSlide="2">
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 3):

There's currently an [open issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10271) related to this. As a temporary workaround, you could try by wrapping that line of code inside of a timeout, or use the `ionViewDidEnter` lifecycle hood:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.slides.slideTo(3, 0); // The 0 will avoid the transition of the slides to be shown
}
```

or

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.slides.slideTo(3, 0); // The 0 will avoid the transition of the slides to be shown
    }, 300)
}
```

Comment: Even in the timeout it is better to check id slides is defined - because the magic number 300 might not work for all devices. You would want to wrap this up in a function and keep calling the function after a sleep till slides is defined.

Comment: Yeah, you could add a check before using the slides, but the issue is not because the slides not being created (since the `this.slides` property is defined, so the slides component already exists). And the 300 is just a number, the goal is to use the `setTimeout` because of how it's handled by the browsers: _Calling setTimeout will add a message to the queue after the time passed as a second argument. If there is no other message in the queue, the message is processed right away; however, if there are messages, the setTimeout message will have to wait for other messages to be processed_